# Haskell, Case inside of Where

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm wondering if there is an idiom to handle the following example. It has to be pretty common, and I don't think you can use where clauses to handle it. Other than writing out two separate cases, I don't know how I would do it.

The general problem is that I want to create a map with a different value depending on a `SelectionType`, like so:

```
type OtherType = { x :: Int, y :: Int, z :: String } deriving (Show)

data SelectionType = A | B

myMapper = map foo someMyTypes
```

where `someMyTypes :: [MyType]` and `foo` is

```
foo :: SelectionType -> MyType -> OtherType
foo sel t = [ x t, y t, z t <> something ]
  where
    case SelectionType of
      A -> something = "a selected"
      B -> something = "b selected"
```

What is the best way to handle this above case, since the above doesn't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move the equation outside of the case.

```
foo sel t = [ x t, y t, z t <> something ]
  where
    something = case sel of
      A -> "a selected"
      B -> "b selected"
```

Comment: Also, you're matching on the variable `sel`, rather than on the type name as @user7428320 was (incorrectly) doing.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky Sure. I assumed that and his several other errors (e.g. not giving `foo` an argument in the `map` expression, declaring `OtherType` as a `type` with record syntax, giving a return type of `OtherType` but a value with a list in...) were introduced in writing the question.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice all of those :-)  Just wanted to call that one out explicitly for the potential benefit of @user7428320, since it seemed potentially more related to their confusion!